# UIButton between two UITableViewCell

Tags: uitableview, uibutton

Basically i need to put a button between to cells. I have a grouped UITableView with only two cells. I cannt get this by using Interface Builder. How can i get this by code ?

[image]

Comment: Does it actually have to be two cells, or can you put a background image on one (large) cell that makes it LOOK like two cells, and then position the button exactly where you want it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is very simple.
Just create a button, set its frame properly, and add to self.tableview in your UITableViewController subclass.

For example :

viewDidLoad() of RootViewController(subclass of UITableViewController)

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
  [super viewDidLoad];
  UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
  button.frame = CGRectMake(0, 30, 50, 50); // May change as needed
  [self.tableView addSubview:button];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have only two cells, why are you using a grouped UITableView instead of your own custom views. I believe a simple solution would be to just make two custom views. One which represents the two cells while the other is smaller view on top of the cells.

If the reason you are using a TableView is that this construct will be reused, then you can create the above implementation as one custom UITableViewCell in Interface Builder then just load it in cellForRowAtIndexPath:

```
    DevCustomCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"DevCustomCell"];
if (cell == nil) {
    NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"DevCustomCell" owner:nil options:nil];
    for (id currentObject in topLevelObjects) {
        if ([currentObject isKindOfClass:[UITableViewCell class]]) {
            cell = (DevCustomCell *)currentObject;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```